# Can a multiplier be used to multiply larger numbers?

Tags: alu

Can you do 8 bit multiplication easily with a 4 bit multiplier.  Efficiently.

Comment: Easily? It depends what do you mean by that. Possible? Yes.

Comment: Can you multiply large (decimal) numbers with pen and paper? If you can, then it can also be done electronically. The method is *exactly* the same, only now with 4 bit binary numbers.

Comment: @jippie Well, your pen-n-paper is not limited by 4 bits...

Comment: @EugeneSh. My pen is limited from 0..9, my paper is the memory. There I gave away part of the solution, you need a piece of paper ... memory.

Comment: @jippie Probably we get the question differently. Which is no surprise as it is pretty vague :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a small multiplier to do large multiplication operations. As jippie says, it's exactly what you do when you multiply multi-digit decimal numbers by hand: You multiply each pair of digits in your head, and write down the partial results and then add them up. This is radix-10 multiplication.

You can do the same thing with 4-bit binary numbers (radix-16 or hexadecimal), or even 8-bit binary numbers (radix-256) or larger. The principle is exactly the same.

It's easiest if both numbers are unsigned. If either one is negative, negate it, and then later figure out what the sign of the result needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the multiplier alone. You also need the ability to perform addition (either on the complete width of your result in one step or in smaller steps with carries).

Normally multipliers have an output that is twice as wide as their inputs so they can multiply all combinations of inputs without overflowing. I will assume that by "4 bit multiplier" you mean a multiplier with two four bit inputs and an 8 bit output. I will also assume that all numbers are unsigned (signed aritmetic makes things more complicated)

Lets say you have two 8 bit numbers A and B. We can treat each 8 bit number as being made up of two 4 bit numbers which we will call AH, AL BH and BL.

A = AH * 2<sup>4</sup> + AL

B = BH * 2<sup>4</sup> + BL

Therefore

A * B = (AH * 2<sup>4</sup> + AL) * (BH * 2<sup>4</sup> + BL)

Multiplying that out gives us

A * B = AH * BH * 2<sup>8</sup> + AH * BL * 2<sup>4</sup> + AL * BH * 2<sup>4</sup> + AL * BL

The multiplications by 2<sup>4</sup> and 2<sup>8</sup> are just fixed bit shifts. So we can implement this with our 4x4 multiplier and a suitable adder (either an adder wide enough to do the addition in one step or an adder with carry in and out).

This can be extended to larger input and output values. Obviously the larger your inputs and outputs get the more multiplications and additions you will have to do. The process is essentially long multiplication in hexadecimal.